# "upgrade" vs. "upgrading"

Tags: word-choice, nouns

I'm taking about software.

I think "upgrade" can be used as a noun. So we can say "system upgrade", right?

And can we say "system upgrading" for the same meaning?

Comment: Have you searched for the terms "system upgrade" and "system upgrading" and compared the results? What did you find?

Comment: "system upgrading" is also used. But I'm not sure if it is grammatically correct.

Comment: Can you use it in a sentence? In some cases it would work, but in others it would not. Are you using it as a noun or as a verb?